# Fadeout effect using react/ decrement photo length

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can I achieve a fade-out effect with each photo card and then decrement the length of the photos after the fadeout effect? Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-herschel-f12gq. I got a solution but the solution doesn't work, when I press each photo. Does anyone know the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-pine-ckph1

In React, the way to modify a component is according to its props/state. Update the state on click of the picture container, then use that to add a class.

Pictures.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../css/utilities.css";
import "../css/main.css";

class Pictures extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fadeOut: false
    };

    this.fadeOut = this.fadeOut.bind(this);
  }

  fadeOut() {
    this.setState({ fadeOut: true }, function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("length").innerText--;
      }, 200);
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.picture);
    const { title, thumbnailUrl } = this.props.picture;
    return (
      <div
        className={
          "picture card container" + (this.state.fadeOut ? " fadeOut" : "")
        }
        onClick={(event) => this.fadeOut(event)}
      >
        <img src={thumbnailUrl} alt="" />
        <h1 className="title">{title}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Pictures;
```

The class then applies the fade out effect smoothly using CSS:

main.css

```css
.picture {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.picture.fadeOut {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Other recommendations:

- The above code runs in place of jsonPlaceholder.js, to better follow framework conventions and to only use CSS for styling
- In HTML, each [id](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_id.asp) attribute must be unique, so you can't set `id="picture"` if you will have more than 1 picture element
- Each image should have an [alt](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_img_alt.asp) attribute

Comment: You're welcome! I hope the answer was helpful to you. You take care too :)